# String comparison with integer in [[ test

Tags: bash, command-line, posix

I was looking at discussion between Kusalananda and xhienne [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396828/85039), where it's mentioned `[ "" -ge 2 ]` not being a valid test producing an error in `bash --posix` and other POSIX-compliant shells.

```
bash-4.3$ [ "" -gt 10 ]
bash: [: : integer expression expected
bash-4.3$ [ '' -gt 10 ]
bash: [: : integer expression expected
```

All good there. Out of curiosity, I tried the same with `[[`.

```
bash-4.3$ [[ "" -gt 10 ]] && echo "YES"
bash-4.3$ [[ "" -gt 0 ]] && echo "YES"
bash-4.3$ [[ "" -gt -1 ]] && echo "YES"
YES
bash-4.3$ [[ "" -eq 0 ]] && echo "YES"
YES
```

As you can see, no errors and it's actually evaluated as numeric expression with "" being equal to 0. So what exactly is happening here ? Is `[[` simply being inconsistent with the old `test` or POSIX ? Is it simply performing string comparison rather than numeric comparison ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One difference between `[` and `[[` is that `[` does *not* do arithmetic evaluation but `[[` does:

```
$ [ "2 + 2" -eq 4 ] && echo yes
bash: [: 2 + 2: integer expression expected
$ [[ "2 + 2" -eq 4 ]] && echo yes
yes
```

The second subtlety is that, wherever *arithmetic evaluation* is performed under bash, empty strings evaluate to 0.  For example:

```
$ x=""; echo $((0 + x))
0
$ [[ "" -eq 0 ]] && echo yes
yes
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is
>   performed before the expression is evaluated.  Within an expression,
>   shell variables  may  also  be  referenced  by  name without using the
>   parameter expansion syntax.  A shell variable that is null or unset
>   evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the    parameter
>   expansion syntax.  The value of a variable is evaluated as an
>   arithmetic expression when it is referenced, or when a variable which
>   has  been  given  the integer attribute using declare -i is assigned a
>   value.  **A null value evaluates to 0**.  A shell variable need not have
>   its integer attribute turned on to be used in  an expression. [*Emphasis added]*

#### Aside: Security Issues

Note that bash's arithmetic evaluation is a potential security issue.  For example, consider:

```
x='a[$(rm -i *)]'
[[ x -eq 0 ]] && echo yes
```

With the `-i` option, the above is safe but the general lesson is not to use bash's arithmetic evaluation with un-sanitized data.

By contrast, with `[`, no arithmetic evaluation is performed and, consequently, the command never attempts to delete files.  Instead, it safely generates an error:

```
$ x='a[$(rm -i *)]'
$ [ "$x" -eq 0 ] && echo yes
bash: [: a[$(rm -i *)]: integer expression expected
```

For more on this issue, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172109/53604).

Comment: I see. `[[` does arithmetic evaluation, that's what was missing.  I think you should put that as the top point

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Very good.  I re-ordered the two points in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, posix test (`[`) would not convert an string to a number on numerical comparisons:

```
$ sh -c '[ 2+2 -eq 4 ]'
sh: 1: [: Illegal number: 2+2

$  dash -c '[ 2+2 -eq 4 ]'
dash: 1: [: Illegal number: 2+2

$ bash -c '[ 2+2 -eq 4 ] && echo "YES"'
bash: line 0: [: 2+2: integer expression expected
```

However, not all shells work in the same way:

```
$ ksh -c '[ 2+2 -eq 4 ] && echo "YES"'
YES
```

#### Usual workaround

Make sure that a null or empty value is converted to 0 (works on most shells)

```
$ dash -c 'a=""; [ "${a:-0}" -gt 3 ] && echo "YES"'
```

#### Use arithmetic

Use arithmetic expansion ( may also convert values as `2+2` in some shells (not dash) )

```
$ dash -c 'a=""; [ "$((a+0))" -gt -3 ] && echo "YES"'
YES
```

## Use [[

The use of the `[[` test will convert most strings that would become a number (even if not wanted) in shells that allow `[[`:

```
$ [[ "2+2" -gt 3 ]] && echo "YES"
YES
```

Comment: I was looking more at the "why" of such behavior occurs in `[[`,which your answer doesn't seem to touch on, but still relevant information. I'm curious why `ksh` implements `[` that way.

Comment: Well, it does: `convert most strings that would become a number`. That is the reason. As for the philosophical reason on the mind of the programmer that implemented it in such a way, you should ask him. @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: lol, trust me, if I had David Korn's email, I would XD

Comment: [This](http://www.kornshell.com/~dgk/) may be still valid ;-) or search github. @SergiyKolodyazhnyy