# Bash string to integer comparison

Tags: bash

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396895/string-comparison-with-integer-in-test) I see the `[[` allows comparison between string and integer.

```
    [usr1@host dir]$ echo $count1
    [1] "0"

    [usr1@host dir]$ echo $count2
    13188

    [usr1@host dir]$ if [[ $count1 -ne $count2 ]]
    > then
    > echo "NE"
    > fi
    bash: [[: [1] "0": syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[1] "0"")

   #this worked fine at one point
   if [[ $count1 -ne $count2 ]] then
      echo "NE"
   fi
   syntax error near unexpected token 'then'  

   if [[ $count1 -ne $count2 ]];    then
      echo "NE"
   fi
   [[: [1] "0": syntax error: operand expected (error token is "[1] "0"")
```

I am very confused with the way the syntax works. How do we tackle different scenarios?  How to prevent the syntax errors irrespective of the value changes(im guessing thats the reason it gives error now).

Comment: (1) Does your `$count1` value really include brackets and quotes?  What sort of result do you expect from [input like that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)? (2) In your first example, the `]]` and the `then` are on different lines.  If you put them on the same line, you must put a ``;`` between them.

Comment: @G-Man Simply comparing the count of records from 2 different sources. Which syntax should i be using?

Comment: @G-Man Ooh Sorry .. Now only i understood the "[1]" was part of the output of `count1`. Will try again.. Thanks

Comment: @sjd: If the output of `count1` is really: `[1] "0"`, then `!=` should be used in `if` condition to compare the `string` and a `number`. Eg: `if [[ "$count1" != "$count2" ]] ;then echo "NE"; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `count1` variable contains the string `[1] "0"`.  This is a eight character string that is *not* an integer.

Even if the value had been just `"0"`, the test `[[ $count1 -ne $count2 ]]` with `$count1` being `"0"` is *very different* from `[[ "$count1" -ne "$count2" ]]` with `$count1` being the single character string `0`.

Comment: even worse, `count1` seems to contain the seven characters `[1] "0"`. Same syntax error, though.

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah, I missed that. I'll update in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Actually the data in count1 was transferred from a R Function. Which always returns the index [1] with the result. once that issue is resolved i cound fix it thanks